# Expose Togglz Admin console in Spring Boot on management-port

Tags: spring-boot, togglz

By default Togglz admin console runs on application port (configured by `server.port` property). I want to expose it on `management.port`. My question: is it possible?

Comment: For future visitors: this has been implemented: https://github.com/togglz/togglz/issues/190 and will be available in `2.4.0` RC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If you use Togglz >= 2.4.0 then this feature is available out of the box.**

For older releases solution is below:

I managed to expose a raw servlet on `management.port` by wrapping it with `MvcEndpoint`. 
The easiest way to do it to use Spring Cloud module which does all the job for you (for example in the HystrixStreamEndpoint):

```
public class HystrixStreamEndpoint extends ServletWrappingEndpoint {

    public HystrixStreamEndpoint() {
        super(HystrixMetricsStreamServlet.class, "hystrixStream", "/hystrix.stream",
                true, true);
    }

}
```

In the case of `TogglzConsoleServlet` there is unfortunately one more hack to do with path's due to the way it extracts prefix from request URI, so the whole solution looks a little bit ugly:

```
@Component
class TogglzConsoleEndpoint implements MvcEndpoint {

    private static final String ADMIN_CONSOLE_URL = "/togglz-console";
    private final TogglzConsoleServlet togglzConsoleServlet;

    @Autowired
    TogglzConsoleEndpoint(final ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        this.togglzConsoleServlet = new TogglzConsoleServlet();
        togglzConsoleServlet.init(new DelegatingServletConfig(servletContext));
    }

    @Override
    public String getPath() {
        return ADMIN_CONSOLE_URL;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSensitive() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<? extends Endpoint> getEndpointType() {
        return null;
    }

    @RequestMapping("**")
    public ModelAndView handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        HttpServletRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new HttpServletRequestWrapper(request) {
            @Override
            public String getServletPath() {
                return ADMIN_CONSOLE_URL;
            }
        };
        togglzConsoleServlet.service(requestWrapper, response);
        return null;
    }

    private class DelegatingServletConfig implements ServletConfig {

        private final ServletContext servletContext;

        DelegatingServletConfig(final ServletContext servletContext) {
            this.servletContext = servletContext;
        }

        @Override
        public String getServletName() {
            return TogglzConsoleEndpoint.this.togglzConsoleServlet.getServletName();
        }

        @Override
        public ServletContext getServletContext() {
            return servletContext;
        }

        @Override
        public String getInitParameter(final String name) {
            return servletContext.getInitParameter(name);
        }

        @Override
        public Enumeration<String> getInitParameterNames() {
            return servletContext.getInitParameterNames();
        }
    }
}
```